# meaning of Break a deal

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I just listened to this news: http://one.npr.org/i/592647800:592647801

(Please listen at 00:10)

And I am not sure whether she is saying “South Korean officials who broke a deal” or “who brought a deal” at 00:10. 
I think she said “broke a deal”, but I don’t understand what deal the Korean official broke. 
Could you please help me?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Respectfully, she said "brokered" a deal. Brokered means set the deal up or made the arrangements for it, or maybe even participated in negotiations for the deal.